# A single-conf, virtual-host-free, webserver for a few small-volume WordPress websites

Tags: linux, open-source, web-browser, wordpress, apache

I have a DigitalOcean/Linode 5$ Ubuntu 16.04 machine with Bash and Nginx on which I have a few very small WordPress websites (see below).

- Up to 20 webpages each.
- Up to 20 images/animations in each website (usually, each image/animation file doesn't weigh more than 250kb).
- up to 1 video in each site (any video is embedded from YouTube/DailyMotion).

### Current state

I'll explain the current state in three parts:

1. Even though I raise my own sever environments on DigitalOcean/Lindoe, I often don't have the spare time to give on research for solving problems in Apache/Nginx (see below).
2. Given my sites are basically identical data volume, and more or less spend the same amount of machine and webserver resources, I'd like to ask the following.
3. I don't want to use a shared server if I have a better option with minimally-managed-cloud like DO/Linode, and I don't want a maximally-managed-cloud because these are usually very expansive.

### Desired state

Is there a free software and gratis webserver, which isn't Apache or Nginx, which includes object caching, that I could install on my machine without needing to configure pretty much anything? Just something with 1 directives similar to all sites.

I must have the time I spend on configuring Apache/Nginx on things like site building and marketing, this is mainly from survival reasons.

Please help me. I know this question might be a better fit for Software Recommendations StackExchange, but I ask to keep it here or at least close it and comment otherwise I could find myself without a rooftop.

### My question

What software would you regard as the most fitted?

Comment: I'd look at a hosting control panel.  Of all of those out there, I'd recommend looking at ISPConfig

Comment: Hello @ivanivan. I think you mean to a shared server / maximally-managed cloud, but I don't desire such solution.

Comment: Are the web pages 100% static or are there dynamic parts such as forms or login-only content?

Comment: All webpages of all my websites have some dynamicity potentially.

Comment: I think you don't understood the comment from ivanivan. It is a solution apparently better than what you are requiring. You can install that solution at your machine on DigitalOcean. You don't make it clear if you sell those websites or if they promote something you do, but if it is the first, it is really the best thing you can do...
It is the kind of software you see on shared servers, but you install it on your private one, and do whatever you want to do with it.

Comment: @flavio I am not a freelance creating and selling websites. This is only for publishing a few small websites with low traffic not for customers.

Comment: Ok, but why you think ISPConfig or other tool like that is not for you?

Comment: I don't. I have no idea what that is. I might have confused something with another.

Comment: It's the first comment you responded on this thread. look [here](https://www.ispconfig.org/).